# Which is more efficient: myType.GetType() or typeof(MyType)?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-type

Supposing I have a class `MyType`:

```
sealed class MyType
{
    static Type typeReference = typeof(MyType);
    //...
}
```

Given the following code:

```
var instance = new MyType();
var type1 = instance.GetType();
var type2 = typeof(MyType);
var type3 = typeReference;
```

Which of these variable assignments would be the most efficient?

Is performance of GetType() or typeof() concerning enough that it would be beneficial to save off the type in a static field?

Comment: Are you getting the instance at runtime (dynamic, generics?) or is it specified at compiletime?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I'm simply asking in the context of the exact code that I have provided.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`typeof(SomeType)` is a simple metadata token lookup

`GetType()` is a virtual call; on the plus side you'll get the derived type if it is a subclass, but on the minus side you'll get the derived class if it is a subclass. If you see what I mean. Additionally, `GetType()` requires boxing for structs, and doesn't work well for nullable structs.

If you know the type at compiletime, use `typeof()`.

Comment: How does `GetType` require boxing for structs?

Comment: @Dan because it is a virtual call that cannot be overridden. All the other struct methods (Equals, ToString, GetHashCode, etc) can be overridden, which allows them to be called without boxing via either call or constrained-call. But to call a non-overridden method on a struct requires boxing and then calling the virtual method on object.

Comment: Got it.  I've never thought about that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan one interesting observation there, though, is that in all non-generic cases involving structs the compiler could actually (but it doesn't) replace the GetType() with a typeof. Although the "correct" behaviour in the case of nullable-T is questionable.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with type2. It doesn't require instantiating an instance to get the type. And it's the most human readable.

Comment: Those are good points, but I'm concerned about efficiency more than I am about readability.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to find out is to measure.

The "type1" variant isn't reliable or recommended in any way, since not all types can be constructed. Even worse, it allocates memory that will need to be garbage collector and invokes the object constructors.

For the remaining two options, on my machine "type3" is about twice as fast as "type1" in both debug and release modes. Remember that this is only true for my test - the results may not be true for other processor types, machine types, compilers, or .NET versions.

```
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var y = typeof(Program).ToString();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var y = typeReference.ToString();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

That said, it's a bit alarming this question is being asked without a clear requirement. If you noticed a performance problem, you'd likely have already profiled it and know which option was better. That tells me that this is likely premature optimization - you know the saying, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Programming code is not measured only by performance. It's also measured by correctness, developer productivity, and maintainability. Increasing the complexity of your code without a **strong** reason just transfers that cost to somewhere else. What might have been a non-issue has now turned into a serious loss of productivity, both now and for future maintainers of the application.

My recommendation would be to always use the "type1" variant. The measurement code I listed isn't a real world scenario. Caching typeof to a reference variable likely has a ton of side-effects, particularly around the way .NET loads assemblies. Rather than having them load only when needed, it might end up loading them all one every use of the application - turning a theoretical performance optimization into a very real performance problem.

Comment: Apologies if the reply was a bit preachy, I'm just imagining Google picking this up and thousands of beginner developers suddenly throwing away the typeof() operator!

Answer (score 3):

They're rather different.

`typeof(MyType)` gets a `Type` object describing the `MyType` type resolved in compile-type using the `ldtoken` instruction.

`myInstance.GetType()` gets the `Type` object describing the runtime type of the `myInstance` variable.

Both are intended for different scenarios.

You cannot use `typeof(MyType)` unless you know the type at the compile-time and have access to it.

You cannot use `myInstance.GetType()` unless you have an instance of the type.

`typeof(MyType)` is always more efficient, but you cannot use if you don't see the type at the compile time. You cannot use `typeof(MyType)` to learn the real runtime type of some variable, because you don't know the type.

Comment: I understand their differences as far as use is concerned.  For the example I posted, the results will be the same type objects.  My question is which is more efficient and why?

Answer (score -1):

Both basically the same. Although typeof can be used on a non-instance class like

```
typeof(MyClass);
```

But

```
MyClass.GetType();
```

won't even build since you need to have an instance of the class.

Long story short, they both do the same job in different context.

Comment: I understand that all 3 of the variable assignments I provided are functionally equivalent, but I'm wondering which is more efficient.

Comment: Technically speaking typeof will be quicker.

Comment: I only ever speak technically.  I don't know how to not.  What makes you say that it is more efficient?

Comment: I have revised my position. Since typeof(Class) return a System.Type object, both syntax form will use the same mechanism. As said before, the only difference is that typeof can only be used on a non-instanced class and Object.GetType() requires that the object is instanciated.

Comment: What does a "non-instance class" even mean?

Comment: A class that is not instanced, like : int. Not an object declared with the int type.

Comment: Classes/types are not instances/objects. Objects are not declared with a type, variables are. Objects/instances can be created/constructed from a type/class.

Comment: With the introduction of object-oriented programming the same word, "object," refers to a particular instance of a class. Excerpt from Wikipedia. I might have expressed myself badly, but it is what I meant. A "non-instanced" class is the type, an "instanced" class is an object.